# Why does my curl command not working correctly?

Tags: curl

```
quinnliu@04:~> curl www.google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=ssl&amp;ei=b7axU9STEYmd8AbT1oCwAw">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Why don't I get the whole google front page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a HTTP status code 302 indicating the page you are looking for has moved. Most web browser would automatically fetch the page at the new location but curl doesn't. 
The content of the answer give you the actual address to fetch in the HREF.

Also you can use the -i option to view the response headers and not just the body.

Comment: You could use the -L option to tell curl to follow redirects.